# Alternate query to join two separate queries

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hive, teradata

Can I combine `q1` and `q2` into a single query?

I need the alternative query in Hive.

```
SELECT q3.*
FROM   (
           (
               SELECT prod_id,
                      prod_name,
                      cust_id
               FROM   sell_info
               GROUP BY
                      prod_id,
                      prod_name,
                      cust_id
           )q1
           JOIN
           (
               SELECT cust_name,
                      cust_address
               FROM   cust_info
               WHERE  cust_type LIKE 'Reg%'
           )q2
           ON q1.cust_id = q2.cust_id
       ) q3;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `JOIN` the two tables `cust_info` and `sell_info` directly without the need of the subqueries, like so:

```
Select DISTINCT *
FROM sell_info AS s
INNER JOIN cust_info AS c ON s.cust_id = c.cust_id
WHERE c.cust_type like 'Reg%';
```

**Note that:** There was no need to `GROUP BY prod_id, prod_name, cust_id`, and in the same time you are selecting *only* those three columns:

```
   SELECT prod_id,
          prod_name,
          cust_id
   FROM   sell_info
   GROUP BY
          prod_id,
          prod_name,
          cust_id
```

This simply can be achieved using the `DISTINCT` keyword only without the need of the `GROUP BY`. The `DISTINCT` eliminates the duplicates that are coming because of the `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this also:

```
SELECT a.prod_id,
       a.prod_name,
       a.cust_id,
       b.cust_name, 
       b.cust_address
FROM  sell_info a 
inner join cust_info b on  a.cust_id = b.cust_id 
where b.cust_type LIKE 'Reg%'
```

Comment: you forgot about the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join if you want to see only those customer and product's data whose `cust_is` exist in both the tables.

```
Select prod_id,
       prod_name,
       cust_info.cust_id,
       cust_name,
       cust_address 
from  sell_info inner join cust_info 
      on sell_info.cust_id=cust_info.cust_id 
where cust_type LIKE 'Reg%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer using inner join is right.

If you want a faster query you can use Intersect as follows:

select cust_id FROM sell_info
Intersect
select cust_id FROM cust_info;

It is twice as fast as inner join but the only disadvantage is that you can only get fields which are common in both the tables. If you need the other fields then the best option is inner join.